# How are errors taken into account whilst calculating probability of an event occurring?

Tags: probability

If there exists some unknown errors (say, the subject being tested is biased but remains silent) whilst conducting an experiment, how does one take those errors into account while calculating the probability of a favourable event occuring related to the experiment? Do we have any pre-existing measures to anticipate such errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if your variables are observed with some error then one can apply an [error in variables model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models).  This would be appropriate if say you were using weight to predict risk of heart attack in patients but the scale was known to be broken and would return a corrupted measurement of the weight (assuming the errors are iid with mean 0).  Assuming we had some object for which we knew the exact weight, we could use that to first estimate the variability in the scale and then use that estimate downstream in our model.

What you describe in your post (a subject refraining from answering some question) is a form of bias, and without knowing the mechanism of the bias it can be hard to correct for.  The difference between error and bias is an important one to underscore.  An *error* means that the measurement does not reflect the true underlying thing being measured.  In our scale example, the difference between the true weight and the weight read from the scale is the error.  A *bias* is the systematic tendency for errors to go in one direction or another (roughly speaking).  Again referring to the scale, perhaps I step on the scale when measuring people making them consistently look heaver than they are in reality.

In your example, and as Alexis notes, there may be pressure to conform to injunctive social norms.  If the subjects have violated the norm, they may be less willing to tell the truth than had they not violated the norm.  This can result in differential bias.  As an example, again crediting Alexis, when asked "Have you ever shoplifted" there may be a pressure for people who have shop lifted to respond "no".  This pressure creates an error (difference between truth and measurement) and will also cause a bias (systematic tendency for the measurements and truth to be misaligned among shoplifters because there is a social pressure to say you didn't shoplift).

Comment: "our answers and hence data are likely going to be incorrect hence biasing the answers" This is a poor example, because it does not differentiate **error** from **bias**. Contrast with answers to questions about engaging illegal or taboo activity (shoplifting, or taking LSD, or something like that): a person who *has not* engaged in that kind of behavior may be less likely to answer "Yes, I have done that," if they cannot recall definitively that they have not, whereas a person who *has* engaged in that kind of behavior may be likely to answer "No, I have not done that," if they cannot recall.

Comment: The social sanction on the behavior creates a biased "default" answer when someone cannot remember. But not remembering by itself is not bias. (Contrast with missing completely at random from not missing at random processes.)

Comment: @Alexis Point taken.  I've edited my answer to more clearly differentiate between error and bias.

Comment: Awesome! :) (I already upvoted you, BTW :)